# Does $180i = \pi(i)$ through euler's identity by $e^{90i} = 0 + i$

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, trigonometry, trigonometric-series, euler-mascheroni-constant

I have a strange question:
If $e^{ix} = cosx + isinx$
then shouldn't $e^{90i} = cos90 + isin90$
Which should simplify to $e^{90i} = 0 + i$ 
making $e^{90i} = i$ 
But we already know that $e^{\pi i} = i^{2}$ 
so doesn't $e^{2\cdot90i} =e^{\pi i}$ 
which should mean $180i=\pi i$.
did i miss something or am i stressing over something unimportant?

Comment: $e^{ix}=\cos{x}+i\sin{x}$ only works if $x$ is in radians.

Comment: Wow okay that does solve everything as 2(value of 90 degrees to radians) Does approach pi.

Comment: @RamMenon I'm not sure what your question is, but the idea is $e^{i\theta}=\cos\theta+i\sin\theta$ holds for $\theta$ in radians. So, in degrees, that would be $\frac{\pi\theta}{180^\circ}$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For equations, please refer to this [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: You should use radians, not degrees

Comment: $e^{90 i} = \cos(90) + i \sin(90) \approx -0.44807361612 + 0.8939966636 \, i \ne i$.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are forgetting is that degrees are a unit. Radians are measured unitless. Therefore, we always need to specify the degree symbol. So yes, if we add the degree symbols, the statements are correct.